# Newline in constant error in &nbsp;x

Tags: asp.net, newline

I get the below error when it comes to executing the below online.

> Newline in constant

I got this code sample from an outside project

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblExt" Text='<%# "&nbsp;x" + Eval("Ext") %>'
```

Once I remove `"&nbsp;x"` <- this code segment, the error is no longer there.
As I know `&nbsp;` denotes a space charactor
But what is the meaning after appending `x` to it.(`"&nbsp;x"`)

Comment: It just adds the letter x before the data contained in "Ext", so `1234` will show up as `x1234`. You can just add an actual space if it's needed and it should be fine. I'm not sure why that's causing an error; it doesn't really match up with `Newline in constant`. Or this might work (?): `'&nbsp;x<%# Eval("Ext") %>'`. (I can't remember if you can add text like that.)

Comment: FYI: `&nbsp;` is a *non-breaking* space, not just a regular space. [info](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below code and it worked.

```
ext='<%# "x" + Eval("Ext")%>'
```